# Problem with calling function with Alto Router package in PHP

Tags: php, altorouter

I have a problem with calling function using alto routing. On index.php I I have my route that calls function that is in another file (test.php) and those two files are in the same directory (root). I get no response, but when I put that function from test.php to index.php where are my routes then it works and I need that function to work in test.php file. I tried putting 'require(index.php)' in test.php file but it doesn't work. Any help is appreciated if someone knows workaround for this. Here is my code.

index.php

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new AltoRouter();

$router->map('GET','/test', 'test.php', 'testfunction'); // HERE IS THAT ROUTE!!!

$match = $router->match();

if ( is_array($match) && is_callable( $match['target'] ) ) {
    call_user_func_array( $match['target'], $match['params'] ); 
} else {
    header( $_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . ' 404 Not Found');
}
```

test.php

```
<?php

require 'index.php';

function testfunction()
{
    echo "YES IT WORKS!";
}
```

Comment: My guess is `test.php` isn't included in a way where `testFunction` is loaded in time. You can't include a file from another file that's not been included, either, even if the other file has been included.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Can you suggest some solution?

Comment: See the suggested answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is speculative, since I don't know AltoRouter, however if each page has it's own (single) specific function, you can return the function as a closure:

```
<?php // ./test.php

return function () {
    return "YES IT WORKS!";
};
```

Closures were introduced in PHP 5.3. Then, your router would be something like:

```
$router->map('GET', '/test', require 'test.php');
```

This works because `require` and `include` give the return from the script:

> Handling Returns: include returns FALSE on failure and raises a warning. Successful includes, unless overridden by the included file, return 1. It is possible to execute a return statement inside an included file in order to terminate processing in that file and return to the script which called it. **Also, it's possible to return values from included files. You can take the value of the include call as you would for a normal function.**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

See a sample in action here:

https://replit.com/@userdude/SimpleRouterReturnClosure#index.php

---

If you have 7.4, arrow functions make the syntax much simpler for the example:

```
<?php // ./test.php

return fn() => "YES IT WORKS!";
```

Comment: It works now, but what if I want multiple functions in my test.php? How would I name them in order to be able to differentiate them?

Comment: You're really talking about how to organize your routes. Check out the repl.it `handlers.php` file for how you can organize by namespace and reference each one from a single file. So either each handler has it's own file, or create a file that loads your namespaced handlers, or implement `use` statements to declare the functions in the top of `index.php`, which can then live in files organized separately but only be loaded if used.